# Regex optional space solution

Tags: regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that will allow up to 50 characters for a name plus up to 8 additional characters for a version number. I have a regular expression that is doing that exactly, except for the scenario that someone were to remove the space between the name and version number. Here is the regex:

```
^([\w\W]{3,50})(\s\(v[\d]{1,4}\)){0,1}?$
```

It properly matches this for example:

```
acvbg yuleacvbg yuleacvbg yuleacvbg yuleacvbg yule (v9999)
```

but, if I remove the space between the appended version number, I no longer have a match

```
acvbg yuleacvbg yuleacvbg yuleacvbg yuleacvbg yule(v9999)
```

How do I get both of these examples to work?

Comment: before  regular expression, check for space before first `(`. If not present, add one.

Comment: `[\w\W]` matches everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make the space itself optional:

```
^([\w\W]{3,50})(\s?\(v[\d]{1,4}\)){0,1}?$
                  ^
```

Which allows 0 or 1 space. To allow an arbitrary number of spaces (including none), you can use the `*` quantifier

```
^([\w\W]{3,50})(\s*\(v[\d]{1,4}\)){0,1}?$
                  ^
```

Also, `[\w\W]` means *"a word character or a non-word character"*, which matches any character. So `[\w\W]` can be replaced with `.`.

Lastly, the `{0,1}` at the end of the expression can simply be omitted, since the optionality of the version number is already being expressed by `?`.

Therefore, the expression can be simplified to:

```
^(.{3,50})(\s*\(v[\d]{1,4}\))?$
```